# SlickGrid - Fill grid with values in specific positions

Tags: grid, cell, spreadsheet, edit, slickgrid

I'm with a problem with SlickGrid Scripts. I want to build a grid based on an array with data. This data basically has a value and an address (row and column) where it should be inserted. I can fill the grid with data, but I can't put the values in the specific column and row. For instance, I have value = 3, cellRow = 2 and cellColumn = A. When I'm building the grid I want to put the value 3 in the row 2 and column A.

Any help? I already searched a lot in slickgrid documentation :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure of Slickgrid data in object form is an array of objects:

```
var data = [
    { A: 1, B: 4, C: 6 },
    { A: 5, B: 9, C: 34 },
    { A: 2, B: 10, C: 2 }
];
```

this appears to be what you have. The basic example uses this kind of data.
So, what is the problem?

If you have an array of arrays, eg

```
var data = [
    [ 1, 4, 6 ],
    [ 5, 9, 34 ],
    [ 2, 10, 2 ]
];
```

then you do need to write some javascript to put the data into the first form.